# What is the fastest way to navigate to a project by its name in Eclipse or STS?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, spring-tool-suite

I have a workspace with 100+ projects in Spring Tool Suite. It is becoming very clustered and hard to find what I want.

I often use <kbd>CMD + Shift + R</kbd>  
and <kbd>CMD + Shift + T</kbd>  for opening a file by its name, but I don't remember all of them by heart.

I am in desperate need for a **shortcut** to just jump to a project **by the project name**. Plugins are welcome but I would prefer native solutions.

I have already tried the following, but they are not suitable for my situation:

- Group related projects into `Working set`
- Create a 2nd workspace
- Close rarely used projects

Comment: I rarely encounter such case that I have to navigate by project name.. Maybe you could try this: move to navigation window, and type a letter. Type repeatedly and it will navigate through all projects whose name starts with that letter.

Comment: You can begin typing the actual name you're looking for, e.g. if you type "pri", it'll move to the first project starting with "pri". Just don't type too slowly. ;-)

Comment: @Andreas This is the best solution so far, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will still put an answer here, credit to @Andreas and @cllllluless:

In STS, click on ANY file or ANY project itself, and start typing the first few letters of the target project, e.g. "pri". It will jump to the first project starting with "pri".

---

Note I mention ANY project because the alphabetic order does not matter, you can click on "zoo-project" and typing "pri" will still bring you there to "pri"

Note I mention ANY file because it is not necessary to click on the title of the project, you would click any file